# What is the proper way of setting a mongodb replica set using docker and fig?

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset, fig

What is the proper way of setting a mongodb replica set using docker and fig?

I was trying to follow official [mongodb tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) to create a `fig.yml` file with some replica sets but always got blocked by how to call `rs.initiate()` and `rs.add("<hostname><:port>")` properly.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585452/how-to-initialize-mongodb-replication-set-without-calling-rs-initiate) explaining why I can't start everything just from the `shell`, without calling `rs.initiate()`, so how can I accomplish that?

Oh, and I am using [`mongo:latest`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) (v2.6.5) as base image, without any modifications.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, this is what I did. I'm using docker-compose instead of fig.

In my docker-compose.

```
mongors:                                                                                                
  image: mongo                                                                                          
  ports:                                                                                                
    - "27017:27017"                                                                                     
  volumes:                                                                                              
   - ./mongo:mongo                                                                                      
  entrypoint: mongo/entrypoint.sh
```

In my entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod --port 27018 --replSet rs0 --fork --syslog --smallfiles
mongo --port 27018 --eval "rs.initiate({_id : 'rs0', members : [{_id : 0, host : 'localhost:27018'}]})"
mongo --port 27018 --eval "while(true) {if (rs.status().ok) break;sleep(1000)};"
```

Make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x mongo/entrypoint.sh
```

It's a little hacky, but it works :)

Answer (score -4):

First Stop the mongod service, before setting the replica set

```
 service mongodb stop
```

mongod --port "PORT" --dbpath "YOUR_DB_DATA_PATH" --replSet "REPLICA_SET_INSTANCE_NAME"

```
 mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "D:\set up\mongodb\data" --replSet rs0 --fork
```

It will start a mongod instance with the name rs0, on port 27017. Now start the command prompt and connect to this mongod instance.

In mongo client issue the command **rs.initiate()** to initiate a new replica set.

```
 rs.initiate()
```

To check the replica set configuration issue the command **rs.conf()**.

**rs.conf()** should have the following

```
{
"_id" : "rs0"
"version" : 1,
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" "localhost:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" "localhost:27018"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" "localhost:27019"
    }
]
}
```

Now, you can add the additional nodes to the replication set by referencing the hostname you gave them.

```
 rs.add("localhost:27019")
 { "ok" : 1 }
```

Do this for each of your remaining replication members. Your replication set should now be up and running.

To check the status of replica set issue the command **rs.status()**.

```
rs.status()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not about setting up a replica set on docker/fig, this is about setting it is up in general in a test environment.

Comment: Yes, and also automating the process... the whole point is to start fig or the docker image and not worry about entering more commands or checking status... You just described the link I already had posted in the question